# Define enum in static library

Tags: c, windows, eclipse, static-libraries

I have a file `foo.h` with an `enum`:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

enum foo_e { foo_a, foo_b, foo_c };
typedef enum foo_e foo_t;

foo_t get_foo(char bar);

#endif
```

The file `foo.c` import it (`#include "foo.h"`) and uses it with no problems.

I export a static library of this project thru Eclipse, giving me a `libFoo.a`.

In other project, I use the library and all symbols are resolved, compiled and works fine. Only the `enum` declaration is not recognized. Eclipse tells me that `foo_t`, `foo_a`, `foo_b`, `foo_c` are undefined, while `get_foo` is defined.

Why?

Comment: None of `foo_t`, `foo_a`, `foo_b`, `foo_c` are objects, and so won't appear in (static) libraries.  If you're including the relevant header, and Eclispe can see it, (and assuming you haven't already #defined FOO_H), then this sounds like Eclipse having a bad day.

Comment: I'm including `foo.h` on the project using "foo" as a static library.

Comment: Can you please show the line in the other project that has the error?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with how Eclipse indexes projects. You can resolve this by refreshing Eclipse's index of your project.

1. Right click on the project that gives the error (not the static library) and select `Index > Freshen All Files`
2. Right click again `Index > Rebuild`

Your project should now be able to find all symbols in any included static libraries.